# FOP: java xml -> pdf conversion 6 time slower than from console

Tags: java, xml, pdf, xslt, apache-fop

I am using Apache FOP to generate PDF file from xml with an xsl:fo xsl stylesheet.
Incoming XML (which is stored in a StringWriter) is about 266000-300000 lines. Result PDF is about 250-300 pages.

The same file is produced by Java in about 30-35 seconds. If I'm using just the console, then the same file is produced in about 5-6 seconds.

Here is the excerpt of java code that processes XML and XSL:FO and results in a PDF.

```
Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, outPutStream);
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltFile));

transformer.setParameter("versionParam", "2.0");
transformer.setParameter("interval", messagingService.getReportInterval());    
transformer.setParameter("clientId", messagingService.getReportClientId());
transformer.setParameter("clientName",messagingService.getReportClientName());
transformer.setParameter("transactionTime", messagingService.getReportTransactionTime());
transformer.setParameter("transactionReceipt", messagingService.getReportReceipt());
transformer.setParameter("bruttoAmount", messagingService.getReportBruttoSum());
transformer.setParameter("feeAmount", messagingService.getReportFee());
transformer.setParameter("nettoAmount", messagingService.getReportNettoSum());
transformer.setParameter("currency", messagingService.getReportCurrency());
transformer.setParameter("total", messagingService.getReportTotal());

Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlSource.toString()));
Result result = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong or there is a trick to speed up performance?